# Aufwärmen alter Fragen durch Editieren

Tags: discussion

Ich habe heute bemerkt, dass ein User innerhalb der letzten 2 Tage ein rundes Dutzend Fragen aus den Jahren 2013 und 2014 editiert hat (nur Layoutoptimierungen und Korrektur vor Rechtschreibfehlern). Das waren lauter Fragen, die damals bereits beantwortet wurden, also eigentlich als abgeschlossen gelten können.

Durch das Editieren rutschen diese Fragen in der Liste der aktiven Fragen aber wieder ganz nach oben, und wirken auf viele User, die damals noch nicht dabei waren, oder sich nicht mehr an diese alten Fragen erinnern können, wie neue Fragen, die auf neue Antworten warten. Das ist aber nicht der Fall.

Ich halte es für sinnvoll, dass Fragen wieder an die Position 1 gereiht werden, wenn jemand eine neue Antwort darauf schreibt. Aber ich finde, das bloße Editieren einer Frage, oder gar nur einer Antwort, sollte kein Grund sein, die Frage wieder vorzureihen.

Dasselbe passiert übrigens auch, wenn man nur die Tags einer Frage ändert (wenn man also z.B. den in Ungnade gefallenen `grammar`-Tag löscht oder durch etwas anders ersetzt).

Wäre es nicht sinnvoll, diese Neureihung zu verhindern, wenn nur editiert wird?

Comment: Ich sehe es so wie Du. Eine offene Frage könnte sein, ob man zwischen gravierenden Änderungen der Frage und kosmetischen, "minor edits" (heißen die in der Wikipedia) Änderungen unterscheiden sollte und kann.

Comment: Beachte, dass es sich hierbei um einen zentralen Aspekt des Stack-Exchange-Systems handelt, der sehr unwahrscheinlich geändert wird. Dies ist eben kein Forum, in dem alte Inhalte gewollt verstauben.

Comment: Außerdem möchte ich darauf aufmerksam machen, dass ich in den letzten Monaten regelmäßig Bündel alter Fragen editiert habe – insgesamt um die müssen es um die zweihundert gewesen sein.

Comment: "nur editieren" ist ein bißchen unspezifisch. Immerhin könnte der Edit komplett sinnverändernd sein. Nur, woher soll das System das wissen?

Comment: Relevante Frage auf [meta.se]: [Is there a way to edit a question without bumping it to the front page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23241/255554)

Answer (score 8):

Es ist ein bewusst eingesetztes Feature der Stackexchange-Seiten, dass eine Bearbeitung eine Seite als *aktiv* markiert (und folglich ganz nach oben an die Liste der aktiven Fragen setzt) – wie auch beim Posten neuer Antworten oder beim Ausloben von Bountys. Diese *Aktiv*-Liste ist dazu da, dass Augen auf Postings gelenkt werden, die *verändert* wurden. Diese Augen sollen sein, denn es kann ja sein, dass ein Edit vandaliert hat – und eine Schwelle, unterhalb derer die Edits ungesehen durchrutschen dürfen, kann es nicht geben, denn schon ein einziger Buchstabe kann aus einem sinnvollen einen obszönen satz machen.

Um auf der Fragenseite das »Rauschen« herauszufiltern, bietet sich an:

- auf *neue* Fragen zu stellen – das hat den Nachteil das neue Antworten Fragen *nicht* nach vorne schieben.
- ein Blick auf die bereits gegebenen Antworten zu werfen und dabei gleich zu erkennen, ob die Frage schon zur Zufriedenheit des Fragestellers beantwortet wurde und gegebenenfalls ignorieren.

Das Feature ist für viel zu viele Leute viel zu nützlich als dass es entfernt werden würde.

Comment: +1: Außer dem Inhaltlichen für die Verwendung von *vandalieren*.